# Number of downloads Windows store

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

As a user, how to see the number of Downloads an app has in the Windows App Store?

In Google Play Store, there is a Number of Downloads milestone. Is there something similar in Windows Store? If yes, Please add a link to your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! Here, Windows seems to be withholding info that Google is showing. But in the Windows App Store you can see the "number of ratings" right next to the row of stars, which is somewhat similar as a milestone.

Answer (score -1):

The only place you can see the number of downloads for an app is in the developer of the app dashboard

Comment: Your answer is not accepted because OP asked "as a user", which is opposed to your answer "as the developer". Would be equally useful as "Bill Gates can see the number of downloads".